# Unzip a Password Protected file in SSIS

Tags: ssis

I have problem with Unzipping a Password Protected file in a SSIS Package.
I Always use Execute Process task But this time After the package download zip file from ftp it must unzip it then i use it as flat file.
now the problem is i can't unzip the file cause its password protected.i have the password of file but i don't now how to use it.
is there a command line or some thing?

Comment: can i insert password in argument property of execute process task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally find it...
use a execute process task and set parameter as below:
executable : C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe.....(winrar location)
Arguments : e -o+ -ppassword "filename"........i.e e -o+ -p12345 "D:\TRFolder\TR0426.zip"
Working Directory : D:\TRFolder ....... UnzipPath
peace

Answer (score 1):

You need to find a [command-line tool](http://www.dotnetperls.com/7-zip-examples) that can unzip password protected zip files, then you can use the Execute Process task as usual. If you don't want to hard-code the password into the SSIS package, you could put it in a package variable, populate the variable from a package configuration or a [dtexec parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162810%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and then set the properties of the Execute Process task dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

I got it which actually worked for me.

We need to pass some parameter in the Execute Process task Editor

[image: Click here for Execute Process task Editor image]

executable: `C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe`  [ Source where 7z is installed file]

Arguments: here we have to pass source, password (if any) & destination. followed by `e`(i.e extract)

For example:

```
e "D:\App\File\TextDoc.7z" -p1234@Abcd -oD:\App\File\Extract * -r
```

Here

- `e` means extract
- Source: `D:\App\File\TextDoc.7z`
- password: `1234@Abcd`
- Destination: `D:\App\File\Extract`
- `r`: this is for Read. means the extracted file file will be visible while extracting